# How can I get rid of ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, bean-validation

I'm using JBoss EAP which contains RESTeasy as JAX-RS implementation. I want to have an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` where I can map all exceptions coming from our REST services in one central place.

However, when validating the method parameters with Bean Validation, my `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` is ignored, since `ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper` kicks in.

Other than creating another `ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>` and duplicating my code... is there any way to suppress `ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper`?

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `@Priority(100)`? Overall though the explicit typed `ExceptionMapper` will win when choosing the exception mapper to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of searching I found a possibility to disable that ExceptionMapper in `web.xml`

```
<web-app>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.disable.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper</param-value>
  </context-param>

</web-app>
```